# Generating vertices of the rectified hypercube

Tags: c++, c++11, combinatorics, computational-geometry

The following piece of code generates the vertices of the rectified hypercube in arbitrary dimensions. The 3D case of the rectified hypercube is a [cuboctahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuboctahedron#Cartesian_coordinates) with 12 vertices (±1,±1,0), (±1,0,±1), (0,±1,±1).

The code below works perfectly, I only want to know what optimizations should I consider and/or if faster approaches exist.

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T, size_t N>
void generate_rectified_hypercube(std::vector<std::array<T, N>> &vertices)
{
    std::array<T, N> set;
    std::array<T, N> temp;

    // Initialize set { 2, 1, ..., 1 }

    set[0] = T(2);
    for (size_t i = 1; i < N; i++)
    {
        set[i] = T(1);
    }

    // Generate vertices

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        // Modify set

        set[i] -= T(2);
        std::copy(set.begin(), set.end(), temp.begin());
        std::sort(temp.begin(), temp.end());

        // Add all possible permutations of current set

        do
        {
            vertices.push_back(temp);
        }
        while (std::next_permutation(temp.begin(), temp.end()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally I'm quite fine with your original source, looks nice.

If you are pursuing absolutely top performance (what is the reason? This looks like a function, which should be used only few times trough life cycle of application) - you would have to dig into `std::next_permutation` first, to see if for your special case of various sets of {-1, 0, 1} values you can generate permutations "manually" in a faster way, then the general purpose permutation generator does. Maybe there is a way, but the source will become substantially longer and more complicated.

If you want to stay with `std::next_permutation`, there's little room for improvement, especially without losing some readability of the source.

For example with understanding how the `set` is modified by last `next_permutation`, you can cut out some initializations and sorting like this:

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T, size_t N>
std::vector<std::array<T, N>> generate_rectified_hypercube()
{
    std::vector<std::array<T, N>> vertices;  // result data
    std::array<T, N> set; // set to permute upon
    // Initialize set to { 0, 1, ..., 1 }
    set[0] = T(0);
    for (size_t i = 1; i < N; ++i) set[i] = T(1);

    // Generate vertices

    // Add all possible permutations of initial set (unrolled loop for i=0)
    do {
        vertices.push_back(set);
    } while (std::next_permutation(set.begin(), set.end()));

    for (size_t i = 1; i < N; ++i) { // do the rest of them

        // Modify set to be seed for next group of permutations:
        // "abusing" the known state after last std::next_permutation call
        set[i-1] = T(-1);    // Here was zero previously
        set[i] = T(0);       // Here was first 1

        // Add all possible permutations of current set
        do {
            vertices.push_back(set);
        } while (std::next_permutation(set.begin(), set.end()));

    }
    return vertices;
}

int main()
{
    auto vertices = generate_rectified_hypercube<float, 5>();
}
```

As you can see, I removed the `temp` array (`std::copy` not needed) and I use the know state after last `next_permutation` to avoid `std::sort`. So this is certainly more efficient, but also harder to read and comprehend.

---

One note about your original code:

You don't clear the `vertices` input, which doesn't feel right to me. If the function is named `generate_rectified_hypercube`, it sounds quite functional to me, so calling it twice with the same vector I would expect it to contain only single copy of vertices (your code would add another set after the first one).

For your code probably some name along `add_generated_rectified_hypercube` would be more precise.

In my code I avoided this completely by creating new instance of vertices inside the function, and letting the C++11-post era compilers to optimize "return by value" situation.

And you can still do twice `vertices.push_back(generate_rectified_hypercube<float, 5>());` to get two sets of vertices, to simulate behaviour of your original code (if desired). So the change in API is not limiting such usage, but it shouldn't happen by accident, reusing some non empty vertices.

---

Another edit:

Couldn't resist from showing off, how the function can be further cleaned up for better performance (unrolling the loop for `i == 0` special case, getting rid of `if (0 < i)` in `for` loop).

The real world benefit is of course useless, as the loop is done only N-times (vs permuting N size array inside, which is much more complex).

So just for your fun ;). (BTW, OCD is evil thing, even partial ... hard to dismiss some things from head)

Comment: Good insights. I named it like that because I use it as an initialization step, so it is called only once. Of course if you don't know that it can be misleading. In the meanwhile I also removed the sorting step (although a different way), but I was still copying to a temporary set. Removing both of them is great.

Comment: @plasmacel: and final note... I'm actually not huge fan of templates in C++. The code above will generate binary for each `N`, bloating the exe size fast (if the app uses many different `N`). If this would be my own code, I would move from `size_t N` being part of template parameter to being an input parameter of call, and keep only the *value type* as template. If arrays can't be then defined by dynamic variable, I would drop them in favour of T[] C arrays. This has some drawbacks from OOP cleanness of code, but performance/exe size wins over for my personal taste.

Comment: I'm a huge fan of templates and this function is a part of a such library, so it needs to support that interface. The fears about binary size bloat are highly excessive. Even more that today the storage and the memory are the cheapest part of a computer, while computing power is the most expensive. Actually a template library (if well designed) saves program size in overall compared to a non-template library of the same functionality. This is also true for performance, since templates can generate, precompute and inline together a LOT of things at compile time, even complete algorithms.

Comment: Of course all the generated/inlined content increase the final exe size, however otherwise you would need to create all non-template versions of every possible combinations of these algorithms (which results in orders of magnitude more size bloat), or use a lot of "if" statements in your algorithms (which results in terrible performance overhead in any critical loop). Not to mention that in the latter case you need to compute the constants of your global functions at runtime. It is true that the above function is not a good example of that, but you know what I mean.

Comment: I was talking particularly about above function, and about `N`. As it's usage in the function has very little to do with being template parameter. I'm too lazy to create an exe + objdump of 3+4+5+6 sample to see, if the resulting ASM is really worth it, so I'm leaving you benefit of doubt, but I would go first with input value in this case. I have no problem with the value type, that's perfect fit for template.